# Dynamic LINQ Cast issue

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, casting, dynamic-linq

When I try to execute this ESQL (Cast int to string) with dynamic linq (from this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx))

```
queryable.Where("CAST(PositionID AS Edm.String).Contains(@0)", paramsObj); //PositionID is Int32
```

it throw exception

```
')' or ',' expected
```

My Entity Framework version is 4.0. Any idea how to resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you cann't use `as` inside function call, try change your code like this

```
queryable.Where("(PositionID.ToString().Contains(@0))", paramsObj); //PositionID is Int32
```

**UPDATE:**

most likely in your case may have to use custom function from db

**UPDATE 2:**
i think you cann't use esql with Dynamic LINQ, because it parse string conditions by self rules, so syntax edsl may be wrong for Dynamic LINQ, also not all SQL constructions implement in LINQ to Entities, so if you want use `like operator` you must use `Contains, StartsWith, EndsWith` functions that work only with string
So for solve this you can use storage procedures and functions, or eSQL command, or raw sql

Comment: Not work, ToString is not supported in linq to entity

Comment: @brian, can you provide a little more code and error message?

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."